# How can I get iOS device version using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, device

Is there a way to obtain an iOS *device* version (as opposed to *OS* version) using JavaScript or another browser-based language? For example; iPhone5, iPhone 4S, iPad 3, etc.

I have not been able to locate this information in `navigator.userAgent` (or any methods of `navigator`), as it only reports the OS version (and not the device used). For example, an iPhone5 running 6.1.3 has this user-agent:

`"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25"`

And an iPhone4 running 6.1.3:

`"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25"`

The best I've been able to find is by using the `screen.width` and `screen.height`, as this would at least let me differentiate between iPhone5, iPhone4, and previous generations.

Comment: Sorry I cant check this now as I dont currently have an IOS device around me but You could check with other variables in navigator like navigator.appName, navigator.platform, navigator.product, navigator.vendor, etc to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? If the browser has the same capabilities, then who cares? And if the browser doesn't have the same capabilities, then you can tell using the standard object detect method in JavaScript. Changing functionality based on the user agent is not best practice.

Comment: It is not for changing functionality, it is for a web-based analytics solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can find `iPhone` or `iPad`, and what version of iOS the device is running, but you can't find a model name such as `iPhone 4`.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was some way to do it, but it's looking like you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

`var iOS = parseFloat(('' + (/CPU.*OS ([0-9_]{1,5})|(CPU like).*AppleWebKit.*Mobile/i.exec(navigator.userAgent) || [0,''])[1]) .replace('undefined', '3_2').replace('_', '.').replace('_', '')) || false;`

It return 10.3 on iPhone

Comment: I think in the original post the user was asking about the device version, not the iOS version